# Getting error while testing website in google page speed

Tags: pagespeed

Hi I am trying to test my website on page speed google but getting an error.

**"Attempting to load the page reached the limit of 3 client redirects. The last URL fetched was http://www.example.com/. This may indicate the page is redirecting to itself, or has a loop of redirects."**

Could you please tell me exactly whats the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your page is redirecting to itself. Execute the following command in your terminal.

```
curl -I http://www.example.com
```

Make sure the URL you are testing with returns HTTP/1.1 200 OK.

You can also use some online tools to find the final destination and use that one for testing the page speed. Check this one - `http://redirectdetective.com/`

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks for the reply I have tested the url at "http://redirectdetective.com/" and got `no redirects found` also I have execute the `curl -I http://www.example.com` command and got `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` response.

But still I am getting an error on page speed google.